# In Sass, is it possible to use a selector value as variable

Tags: sass

Is it possible to use the value of a selector as a variable?

```
.warning {
    color:Red;
    border:1px solid #{.warning.color};
}
```

or

```
.total {
    padding-top:#{.font-size};
    color:Red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SASS does not build the object model in mind when parsing the code.

You'll have to keep all the necessary stuff in variables.